# why reference to a local variable returns in this code?

Tags: c++, reference

Why following code works?
Function max is returning a reference to a copy of vector, which is local variable, but it returns 19 (which is the right answer).
I'm using QtCreator 3.5.0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
T& max(std::vector<T> array)
{
   T& result = array[0];
   for (size_t i = 1; i < array.size(); i++)
   {
       if (result < array[i])
       {
           result = array[i];
       }
   }
   return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> testVector;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        testVector.push_back(i);
    }
    std::cout << max(testVector) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You are just lucky - do not depend on it

Comment: If you break the rules, you might go to jail or you might not. Just dont do it

Comment: @hvd yes, sorry, i wanted to say that it wasn't returning a reference to a copy of a vector.

Comment: Aside: `result = array[i];` does not do what you think it does. It assigns to `array[0]`. (Which does not cause immediate problems here, since nothing else reads from `array[0]` until the `return result;`, but will cause problems if you modify the code to take a vector parameter by reference.)

Comment: @hvd I've already found out about this issue using debugger, but it does not explain the main problem

Comment: @andrew554 Well asking about the behavior of undefined behavior is pretty useless, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Returning a reference to a local variable has an undefined behavior. It may work by chance for your usecase, but you shouldn't depend on it. It may (and probably will) break in some horrible way eventually.